# 64 bits integer operation on 64 bits processor with x86 OS

Tags: operating-system, integer, processor

If I have an 64 bits processor, but use a 32 bits OS, how do operations on 64 bits integer perform?

- As fast as on a x64 OS.
- Faster than on x86/32bits but slower than x64/64bits.
- As fast as on x86/32bits.
- Something else?

Comment: A 64-bit integer could be seen as a `long`, `long int`, or `long long int`, depending on what compiler/language you're using.

Comment: Yeah, that was not really my question tough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same as with x86/32bits provided the other characteristics are matching. The 64bits General Purpose registers are not available in 32bit processor mode as well as new instructions.